# I dont know the selector to make the subjects get hidden and visible

Tags: html, css

The HTML and CSS code is as follows;

I am using  `li ul` as selectors to make my subjects hidden but it's not working
and I don't know why. Can some one please help (I am new to programming)

```
<div id="subjects">
    <h3> SUBJECTS </h3>
    <ul class="subjects">
        <li><a href="#"> Introduction To Biochemistry</a> </li>
        <ul>
            <li><a> new</a> </li>
            <li><a> new</a> </li>
            <li><a> new </a></li> 
        </ul>

        <li><a href="#"> Chemistry Of Biomolecules </a></li>

        <ul>
            <li><a> new</a> </li>
            <li><a> new</a> </li>
            <li><a> new </a></li> 
        </ul>          
    </ul>
</div>

li ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
}       

li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Please write your CSS code in write way that we can understand your problem

Comment: Your HTML code is not right according to your CSS. I've edited my answer with the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you want

**Edit**

Also you have error in your HTTML. Your HTML should be like bellow. (Modifying your HTML according your CSS. But this not means that you must write HTML in this way)

```
<div id="subjects">
    <h3> SUBJECTS </h3>
    <ul class="subjects">
        <li><a href="#"> Introduction To Biochemistry</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>new</a> </li>
                <li><a>new</a> </li>
                <li><a>new</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Chemistry Of Biomolecules </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>new</a> </li>
                <li><a>new</a> </li>
                <li><a>new</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
li ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
}

li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to `:hover` over an item that's set to `display: none`.

Comment: Look at my code. `:hover` in not on the `display: none` item (ul). `:hover` is on `li`

Comment: The display should be visible, I ve changed it, but it's still nt working. I thinks he CSS selector used is nt correct I.e, li ul

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting al `ul` tags in `li` tags, but your HTML is the other way around.

If you change your CSS to `ul li { css_here }` it should work.

Also when `position: absolute;` is set to the `li` items, the `ul` item doesn't wrap the items anymore, because they are removed from the document layout flow. So you might want to remove the `position: absolute;`.

Comment: I think he is correct. As you can write `ul li ul` so you can also write `li ul`

Comment: True, but his HTML never does that. So the selector will not find any matching elements.

Comment: Oh, yes. There is error in his HTML code. Thank you

Comment: I ve changed d hover pseudo-class display to visible nd d li ul selector display to hidden, it's still nt working

Comment: You open a `<ul>` and add one `<li>` tag, adding another `<ul>` right after the `li`. A `<ul>` tag cannot be added into another `<ul>` directly.
So you either never meant to wrap the ul's into each other or you want the inner `<ul>` to be in the `<li>`.

Comment: I m sorry, I don't get ur explanation

Comment: @ billy nates- it worked as u explained, bt how do I make it visible using hover, ul:hover li is nt working

Comment: Try removing the `position: absolute` from the `li` items